# Can't get Jedi's autocompletion on SuperTab

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-jedi-vim, plugin-supertab

I installed both plugins using Pathogen, but they don't work together as it should be. That is, if I use TAB, I get SuperTab's completion (autocomplete what I have previously written) whereas if I use CTRL + SPACE I get Jedi's completion (everything from libs: classes, modules, etc).

In theory, if both plugins are installed SuperTab should handle Jedi seamlessly, but that's not my case. I found [this report](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/165) of some people experiencing the same behavior, while others saying it works for them. There is no solution provided though.

The plugins I'm using don't override each other:

```
ls ~/.vim/bundle/
auto-pairs  nerdtree  syntastic    vim-trailing-whitespace
jedi-vim    supertab  vim-airline
```

So what else may be causing this behavior?

vimrc:

```
set nu
set ts=4
set sw=4
set mouse=a
set showmatch
set expandtab
set background=dark
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

execute pathogen#infect()

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple solution, try adding this line to your vimrc:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
```

This will result in the following behavior, which should be what you need in most cases:

```
/usr/l<tab>  # will use filename completion
myvar.t<tab> # will use user completion if completefunc set, or
             # omni completion if omnifunc set.
myvar-><tab> # same as above
```

You can always check `:help supertab-completioncontexts` if you need a more personalized behavior.

What jedi-vim does is set `omnifunc` option to use the function it provides. This means that jedi-vim is only used when performing omni-completion. If you want to force SuperTab to **always** use omni-completion then you can also use the following option **instead** of the above one:

```
let g:SuperTabContextDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"
```

Comment: `let g:SuperTabContextDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"`this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The default for SuperTab is to use `<C-p>` completion, vim-jedi, however, starts with `<C-Space>`. You need to tell SuperTab that you want to use that ;-)

You can configure this with:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = '<C-@>'
```

The `@` refers to the space. You may also want to set:

```
let g:SuperTabMappingForward = '<C-@>'
let g:SuperTabMappingBackward = '<S-C-@>'
```

This is documented in `:help g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType`, `:help g:SuperTabMappingForward`.

Comment: just added those lines and the result is that for autocompletion I need to use CTRL+Space (Jedi), and if I use TAB it adds a TAB (well, 4 whitespaces). I'm excepting to use TAB and get the same output I get using CTRL+Space (i.e. Jedi's output)